# How do I require my tvOS app to use an external controller or bluetooth accessory?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, tvos

It seems there has been some back and forth on this. First Apple said that developers could require external controllers then they removed the ability to require an external controller but now it looks like Guitar Hero Live in the tvOS is marked as '(Bluetooth symbol) Accessory Required'.

Is there a checkbox somewhere in iTunes Connect that allows my app to require an accessory? Also can I require an accessory for my iOS app?

[image: tvos require accessory]